# In Windows form, Can we add a label inside a combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox showing the basic education details which has three categories as Bachelor, Diploma and Schooling. I need to give these three categories as headings each have different values. Is it possible to do so in a windows form in c#?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? An image example will be more helpful

Comment: I think you want something like the optgroup tag used in HTML, am I right? But as far as I know you would need 2 comboboxes one for the categories (bachelor diploma, schooling) and another one that would contain the specific values once the value of this one has been selected.

Comment: Not sure its possible with WinForms but with WPF its relatively easy. http://www.jarloo.com/wpf-combobox-with-groupings/

Comment: I don't understand what you want. In a comboBox you have only one column of Items and no Header. You can owner-draw the Items and make your Grouping Items stand out and you can prevent them from being selected..

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the value that is different from displayed text (Bachelor, Diploma and Schooling), right?

If so, you can implement it as follows :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyComboItem("Bachelor",0));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyComboItem("Diploma", 1));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new MyComboItem("Schooling", 2));
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0) {

                MyComboItem item = (MyComboItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                MessageBox.Show("value of " + item.Text + " is : " + item.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyComboItem {

        private string text;
        private int value;

        public string Text { get { return this.text; } }
        public int Value { get { return this.value; } }

        public MyComboItem(string text, int value) {
            this.text = text;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return this.text;
        }


    }
}
```